# Calling Third Party DLLs within Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am having difficulty in calling a thrid party DLL form within Mathematica.  My code is:

```
     qmConnectLocal = 
         LibraryFunctionLoad["C:\\Windows\\QMClient.dll", 
         "QMConnectLocal" , {String}, Bool]
```

what I get is:

```
    LibraryFunction::btype: Invalid type and/or rank specification in String. >>
```

I am too much of a novice in Mathematica code to understand what it is trying to tell me.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says that it has to be `"UTF8String"` (with quotes) instead of `String`. So what happens when you try

```
qmConnectLocal = LibraryFunctionLoad["C:\\Windows\\QMClient.dll", 
 "QMConnectLocal" , {"UTF8String"}, Bool]
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was it.  I also had to change Bool to Boolean.